# I have had vs I have got

Tags: present-perfect

I've got a camera. I bought it 10 years ago.

I can say:

> I **have had** this camera for 10 years.

Can I also say:

> I **have got** this camera for 10 years.

Is it correct/common in English?

Comment: No, it is not correct the way you mean it.  **Got** in this context means something like "acquired" or "possess right now", so you could say, "I got this camera ten years ago" or (very informally), "I got my camera right here in my backpack."  But both of those refer to a specific moment in time, so you can't use them with "for ten years."

Comment: I'have just realized I asked an idiot question. Sorry guys English is tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct English would be...

> I have had this camera for 10 years.

OR

> I got this camera 10 years ago.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think there is a point in posting a seperate question, but I'd like to know how to say *have got* in the present perfect tense since it's already this tense. So is *I've got this camera for 10 years* correct? If it isn't, how can I rephrase it? Should I post a seperate question?

Comment: @user2738748 "Have got" is actually simple present tense because it's a replacement for "have."  "Have gotten" could technically be used as present perfect, but, typically, English speakers do not use it in this way.  Your sentence is incorrect because you cannot use the present perfect with an exact time expressions (i.e., 10 years). Although, English speakers would not say, "I have gotten a camera."  OR  "I have gotten a camera during the past year."   We would use the sentences I originally gave you.  I cannot think of a time when we would use "have gotten" in the way you're asking.

Comment: @user2738748. Take a look at this site for more help in this area:  http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/present_perfect_tense07.html

Comment: Thans, the explanation is very comprehensive and clear. I think that my sentence is incorrect, because I used the present smple tense with a period of time which started 10 years ago and has lasted until now. My time expression wasn't *exact* - I didn't say *10 years ago*, but *for 10 years*. Are you saing that although it is gramatically correct to say that *you have gotten your cat for 10 years*, you would say that *you have had your cat for 10 years*, because the first sentence is far too informal? Is it as informal as saying *ain't*?

Comment: I understand why it's incorrect to say  *I have gotten a camera* and *I have gotten a camera during the past year.*, I'm (was) wondering how to transform *have got* to the present perfect tense, not what are the differences in usage of the present perfect and past simple tenses.